# Python Function not executing

Tags: python, function

I am trying to understand why the output `print(idx,item)` is not given back on the shell, when I run this program in a python module.

```
def price_of_items():
       items=["pear","apple","grape"]
       prices_items=[]
       for i in items:
           price=int(input("Please enter the price of",+item))
           price_items.append(price)
       for idx, item in enumerate(price_items):
           print(idx,item)
       return

def main():
       option=""
       while option not in "X": #Loop control for when user doesnt exit program
           print("Main Menu")
           print()
           print("A/ItemPricing")
           print("X. Exit")
           option=input("Please select an option A or X from the Menus above")
           option=option.upper()
           while option not in ("A","X"):
               print("Invalid Input")
               option=input("Select either from A or from X")
               option-option.upper()
           if option=="A":
               price_of_items()
           else:
               exit()
   main()
```

Comment: use `while option != 'X'` because if you check if an empty string is in another string, well, then it will be there because it doesn't take up any space

Comment: is main called recursively from main?

Comment: `while option not in "X"` is wrong, you never go into the loop. Use `while option != "X"`

Comment: The code as currently shown would give an indentation error. Any other expectation of its behaviour is based on guessing how it is actually supposed to be indented. Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

I've edited your code a bit so it will work without errors:

- You are refrencing `item` without it being defined.
- The `while` loop should be `while option !=  "X"`
- The list you are refrencing in the function should be `prices_items`

Edited version:

```
def price_of_items():
    items = ["pear", "apple", "grape"]
    prices_items = []
    for item in items:
        price = int(input(f"Please enter the price of {e} "))
        prices_items.append(price)
    for idx, item in enumerate(prices_items):
        print(idx, item)
    return


def main():
    option = ""
    while option !=  "X":  # Loop control for when user doesnt exit program
        print("Main Menu")
        print()
        print("A/ItemPricing")
        print("X. Exit")
        option = input("Please select an option A or X from the Menus above ")
        option = option.upper()
        while option not in ("A", "X"):
            print("Invalid Input")
            option = input("Select either from A or from X")
            option = option.upper()
        if option == "A":
            price_of_items()
        else:
            exit()


main()
```

Output flow:

```
Main Menu

A/ItemPricing
X. Exit
Please select an option A or X from the Menus above a
Please enter the price of pear 12
Please enter the price of apple 13
Please enter the price of grape 14
0 12
1 13
2 14
Main Menu

A/ItemPricing
X. Exit
```

Comment: you kinda should add a bit of explanation as to what and why you changed exactly